# Drupal Internationalization / Translation

Tags: i18n-l10n

When you translate a website using the i8ln module it doesn't automatically translate all the words in fields correct?

Also, what do you need to do to efficiently translate all the words ?

Is it a process that requires manually translating all the text with the i8ln module?

I reviewed some drupal documentation about this but it seems to only be germane to contributing local translations to the server: http://drupal.org/node/11130

I'm looking to have the localization server automatically translate it for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if I completely understand your question correctly, but I think there's some confusion. The Drupal translations from localize.drupal.org and the locale core module, will only help you translate the interface. If there's something missing or you want some custom translations you can always use: http://drupal.org/project/l10n_client - and to keep it up-to date: http://drupal.org/project/l10n_update

The i18n module allows users to translate the content into different languages, but it does not auto-translate. There are some modules that uses Google's APIs to auto translate but one violates Google's TOS and the other one will stop working when google pulls there translation API

- http://drupal.org/project/gtrans
- http://drupal.org/project/i18n_auto

Comment: Ah thanks. That clears up the confusion. Are there any other methods to auto translate?

Comment: Nevermind. I found this module that looks even better: http://drupal.org/project/gtranslate

Comment: Good find, that module seems to be more maintained than gtrans and has a D7 version unlike i18n_auto. I wonder if the following will affect the gtranslate module too: http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/overview.html.

If I had a D6 site I would use i18n_auto the developer is a well known on the Drupal community.

Comment: Sorry I think that gtranslate module is worse than useless. Translations produced by google are much worse than translations written by a human translator, and if non-english readers want to use google translate I think they generally know how to find it. As a website operator I would only want to offer a high quality translation.

Comment: I agree but then again that's not the question I was answering, the question author specifically mentions auto translations.

Answer (score 0):

I found this:
https://drupal.org/project/translation_management
https://drupal.org/project/i18n

More explanations available in this post:
http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/howto-translate-drupal-sites/